# Kohen Gadol and marriage

Tags: halacha, marriage, kohen-priest, parashas-emor, kohen-gadol

We know that a Kohen hedyot may marry a woman who is not a *giyoret*, *gerushah*, *challalah*, or *zonah* (Lev. 21:8) and that the Kohen Gadol may only marry a *betulah* (*ibid.* 13).

Given this, what would happen were the Kohen elevated to the status of Kohen Gadol married to an *almanah* ?

Comment: Yehoshua Ben Gamla did it and Chachamim agreed

Answer (score 6):

[Yevamot 6:4](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishnah_Yevamot.6.4?ven=William_Davidson_Edition_-_English&vhe=Torat_Emet_357&lang=bi) tells us that even if a *kohen* had only betrothed (*eres*) a widow before being appointed *kohen gadol*, he is subsequently permitted to consummate the marriage.